# Trying to lookup data based on multirows and data

Tags: sql

I have a table where I have employee login data stored.  one row for each login.

I have a need to pull out and check each set of employee data where they logined in in multiple states.

example date:

```
EmployeeNumber: EmployeeState
216394      RCAIL     
216394      RCAIL     
216394      RCAIL     
216394      RCAIL     
216394      RCAIL     
216395      IA        
216395      NE        
216395      IA        
216395      IA        
216395      IA        
216395      NE        
216395      IA        
216400      TA        
216400      TA        
216400      TA        
216400      TA        
216400      TA
```

In this example I would like for all rows associated with 216395 to be pulled out so I can view them and reconcile if they are correct.

Comment: What DB is it? what have you tried so far that is not working?

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    EmployeeNumber
from
    [EmployeeTable]
group by
    EmployeeNumber, EmployeeState
having
    count(*) > 1
```